# show html page in iphone application page by page

Tags: ios, uiwebview, epub, ibooks

I want to add feature like epub viewer as similar to ibooks application. So I need to show html or xml or rss feed page in iphone application page wise. What should i do now ?
I worked with webview. But it not shows with page by page. It shows within 1 page.

Let me ask that whether above feature is possible in webview or not ?
If yes then how ?

Do you have any other idea,please share with me.

Please suggest me flow for adding above feature.
It will be great if any one has idea regarding any library or source code .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy problem, we used some javaScript code to achieve this and called it from obj-c with `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(NSString)`
And I wasn't able to find any libraries for that.

Comment: Did you get some logic behind these how to achieve this feature ?

Comment: JS code was made by another person, but I know the idea - when your know screen height and height of lines you can find out how many lines can be putted on the screen. On some event you scroll your long text with js function to next N lines when user swipes screen. Sorry that I am not able to put some code here.